# Find i/o pole of the cascade (BJT)

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, frequency-response, formula-derivation, cascode

I have to obtain the pole of this circuit and the conversion function, but I can not do it .

[image]

How many poles does this circuit have?

And what are their relationships according to the arrangement of the figure above?

*thanks* ❤
[image]

Comment: It's not a cascode amplifier (as per your tag).

Comment: In Behzad Razavi slides, this circuit is mentioned as a bipolar cascade. @Andy aka

Comment: It's neither a cascade nor a cascode as far as I am concerned. Of course if you have a link to somewhere reputable on the web that says it is then I might be convinced.

Comment: Define the Miller Capacitance

Comment: I saw it here, see slide number 60. Here pnp is used instead of npn. What change is seen in the pole wp, y? @Andy aka
link: https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/PatelJay3/frequency-response-48398305

Comment: Yes, that is a cascode amplifier but replacing the NPN with a PNP doesn't make your circuit a cascode amplifier.

Comment: See the link I shared. If we put pnp instead of transistor Q2 which is npn, what will the relations be like? @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75

Comment: Well, look at the question I asked Tony and comment. @Andy aka

Comment: This site isn't a homework answering service like Chegg. If you don't know how to solve something then you need to show where you got into difficulty. Nobody can guess what it is that you find difficult about this and thinking the circuit is cascode is not at all helping you.